# Expect Script - How can the first and last line of a file be validated

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm using Expect to create a CSR file on a remote system. I'm capturing the output from the system and placing it into a file on my local PC (where it is needed).

I need to validate the first and last line of this file to make sure the file looks like the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Originally I was only looking for the last line (or so I thought) by looping through the lines of the file looking for `-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`

```
set fp [ open $csrname ]
while {[gets $fp line] != -1} {
    if { $line == "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" } {
        puts "The Certificate Signing Request file \"$csrname\" has been succesfully created"
    } else {
        puts "The certificate file is invalid."
        puts $line
        exit 41
    }
}
```

I have a flaw in my logic because I end up in the error leg of that `if` statement and exit.

How can I validate just the first and last line of the file?

Comment: Set variables before the while loop to keep track of when you've found those lines and put the else statement after the while loop, so it only `puts` the error after it searches the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

A CSR isn't really all that long; just a few kilobytes at most. We can validate the lot in one go!

```
# Load *everything* from a file at once
set f [open $csrname]
set contents [read $f]
close $f

# Validate it using this regular expression:
set RE {^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n.*\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n*$}
if {![regexp $RE $contents]} {
    puts "The certificate file is invalid."
    exit 1
    # This spot is unreachable, of course...
}

puts "The Certificate Signing Request file \"$csrname\" has been succesfully created"
```

I'd recommend checking that the bit between the separators is only using valid characters too (it's base64-encoded PKCS#10), but that's rather more complicated once you go beyond the basics. Probably best to just confirm that you've not got truncation or something that just isn't a CSR at all.

Comment: Donal, Thank you very much.  The solution you shared works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Donal has a nice answer. Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
set first [exec sed {1q} $csrname]
set last  [exec sed -n {$p} $csrname]
```

or

```
set f [open $csrname]
set lines [split [read -nonewline $f] \n]
close $f
set first [lindex $lines 0]
set last  [lindex $lines end]
```

In either case, you can

```
if {$first eq "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" &&
    $last  eq "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"} {...}
```

Comment: Glenn, your solution also resolves my flawed attempts.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can refer to http://wiki.tcl.tk/1466

[eof] is used to determine whether the channel has reached the end of input.